# How do I pass e.target back to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom

I have a front-end where I track what element has been `click`ed and send it back to the server to do some work on the backend depending on what that element is. The code is setup like so...

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    $.post( '/edit', {el: $( e.target ).serialize()}, function(response) {
        console.log( response );
    });
});
```

But I get `el` as an empty string on the server. What else can I do to get the `e.target` info to my server?

**Update:**

I think my question could benefit from some context.

The basic function of the app is to enable in-page editing. A node server loads the HTML page I want to edit. Clicking on any element on this page lets me change the text in that element, which is then `POST`ed back to the node server, where I use the `cheerio` module to change the DOM representation and overwrite the original HTML file. Reloading the page now gives me the new version of the page with the edits I had made.

But to apply the edits I have made on the front-end, `cheerio` needs the `e.target` to find the right element in its DOM representation and then change the `text`, since many of the elements on the page don't have `id`s.

This is the whole app...

```
var
    express  = require( 'express' )
,   fs       = require( 'fs' )
,   cheerio  = require( 'cheerio' )
,   $        = ''
,   app      = express()
,   html     = ''
,   injected = "<script> \
                    $( 'body').on( 'click', function(e) {  \
                        $( e.target ).text( prompt('Enter new value:') );  \
                        $.post( '/edit', {el: $(e.target).serialize(), newVal: $(e.target).text()}, function(response) {  \
                            alert( response );  \
                        });  \
                    });  \
                </script>";

app.use( express.static(__dirname) )
app.use( express.bodyParser() )


app.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
    fs.readFile( process.argv[2], 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        $ = cheerio.load( data )
        err? console.log( err ): res.send( data.replace('</body>', injected + '</body>') )
    })
})

app.post( '/edit', function(req,res) {
    $( req.body.el ).text( req.body.newVal )
    fs.writeFile( process.argv[2], $.html(), function(err) {
        err? res.send( err ): res.send( 'file saved with changes!' )
    })
})

app.listen( 8080 )
```

I then run the app:

```
node cms.js "E:\Dropbox\sites\index.html"
```

Theoretically, this should let me edit `index.html` "in-page" and without a code editor. But getting the `e.target` back to the server intact remains the hurdle.

**Workaround:**

My current workaround is to just `POST` the entire HTML of the page using `$( 'html' ).html()` so regardless of which element is clicked, I can get the new state of the page in it's entirety and overwrite the existing file with this new state. But I have browser extensions that inject their own HTML/JS and I want to avoid the painful process of stripping those away before saving to file. For that, I need to tell `cheerio` exactly which element has been `click`ed.

Comment: it depends on what you expect to receive at the server side

Comment: what is you are looking for? what kind of data has to be sent

Comment: `serialize` is for converting **form** control elements to a string (name + value). `e.target` is a DOM node, which is an object. Since you cannot simply send such objects between servers, what exactly do you need from the node? How would a "serialized" DOM element look like for you?

Comment: JSON.stringify the props after extracting the ones you want

Comment: @FelixKling Surely you meant to say "One cannot simply _send DOM Objects_ into _a Server_"

Comment: @PaulS.: Does it matter? Server, clients are all just computers anyway ;) And all objects have to be serialized first somehow before they can be sent. But yeah, I basically meant that.

Comment: I've added some more context to help clear things up a bit. I got the point about `serialize()` being the wrong way to go, but the problem of getting `e.target` back to the server still remains.

Answer (score 0):

[Serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) works on forms and generates output similar to what your query string would be, `single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1`

You may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419877/358906), I use it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/3WAhy/1/) to get the html of the button when it's clicked:

HTML

```
<input id="b" type="button" value="click" />
```

JS

```
$("#b").click (function (e) {
    window.alert($(e.target).outerHTML());
});

jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return s
        ? this.before(s).remove()
        : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};
```

Comment: *"The reason why it's empty is because the element you clicked has no innerHTML"*: How do you know that? It's incorrect anyways. If the result is empty, then the target element is neither a `form` element nor a form control element (such as `input` or `select`).

Comment: Thanks, I was editing by the time you were writing your comment ))